# Long label for a tikz picture (Having multiple line label for a tikz shape)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have trouble making a tikz picture label break into couple lines. Here is specific MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
    \begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{action} = [
                        rectangle, draw, 
                        fill=blue!20,
                        text width=6em,
                        node distance=3cm, 
                        text centered
                        ]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [
            action, 
            label=below:Computer: (0 min)
            ] 
            (Receive) {Receive Order};
    \node [
            action, 
            left of=Receive,
            text width=10em,
            node distance=4cm,
            label=below: hey this is a big\\label; what should i do to break it? 
            ] 
            (identify) {I am a big process name};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, tikz doesn't break the line. Am I missing something?

Comment: The label behaves like a normal node: Line wrapping only works if you specify the alignment option (like `align=center`). In this case, you can use `label={[align=center]below: hey this is a big\\label; what should i do to break it?}`, or you can set the alignment option for all of your labels using `every label/.append style={align=center}`

Comment: @Jake sounds like an answer :)

Comment: yeah, can you please write it as an answer? It works thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The label behaves like normal nodes: Line wrapping only works if you specify the alignment option (like `align=center`), in which case you can manually break the lines using `\\`, or by specifying a `text width`, in which case the text will automatically wrap around.

For labels, you can use `label={[align=center]below: hey this is a big\\label; what should i do to break it?}`, or you can set the alignment option for all of your labels using `every label/.append style={align=center}`.